# Pushing object to nested JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json, angularjs

In the following JSON object, I have two dummy products and a nested group of reviews that are siblings to one another:

**product.json**

```
[
{
    "name": "Dodecahedron",
    "price": 2.95,
    "description": "This gem is awesome and has 10 sides.",
    "images": [
        {
            "full": "dodecahedron-01-full.jpg",
            "thumb": "dodecahedron-01-thumb.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [
        {
            "stars": 5,
            "body": "I love this product!",
            "author": "joe@thomas.com"
        },
        {
            "stars": 1,
            "body": "This product sucks",
            "author": "tim@hater.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Hectahedron",
    "price": 8.95,
    "description": "Wonderful 6-sided gem that will please all.",
    "images": [
        {
            "full": "hectahedron-01-full.jpg",
            "thumb": "hectahedron-01-thumb.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [
        {
            "stars": 4,
            "body": "product is awesome, seriously!",
            "author": "james@crazy.com"
        },
        {
            "stars": 2,
            "body": "Seriously sucks, would give 0 if i could",
            "author": "john@hater.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I am using AngularJS to send the newly created JS review object from an HTML form to PHP. But how in PHP do you push this review data to become a sibling IN "reviews" AND target the exact product it should be in? I'm very new to PHP and would greatly appreciate your guidance!

Comment: Code School, Shapping Up with Angular :D

Comment: Can you provide more information what you actually want to achieve in PHP, and what you have at the moment?

Comment: @PatrickBard Haha! Shaping Up with Angular, indeed :) At the moment I have the gem store set up with the comment posting to the page, just no actual server actions altering the JSON. I have worked with PHP to post before but not sure where to go for appending a review to an exact branch.

Comment: This questions was effectively another post:

[PHP: Targeting specific JSON array and appending POST data correctly?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28774507/1284269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, here you need to use the json_decode() function:

```
$productsRreviews = json_decode($_POST['reviews'], true);
```

This will give you a PHP associative array that you can process to do whatever you need to do. For instance:

```
foreach ($productsReviews as $productReviews) {
    $name = $productReviews['name'];
    $price = $productReviews['price'];
    $reviews = $productReviews['reviews'];

    foreach ($reviews as $review) {
        $stars = $review['stars'];
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!