# PHP: Targeting specific JSON array and appending POST data correctly?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a JSON file that, in essence, is structured like this:

```
[{
    "name": "James",
    "reviews": [
        {
            "stars": 5,
            "body": "great!"
        },
        {
            "stars": 1,
            "body": "bad!"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "David",
    "reviews": [
        {
            "stars": 4,
            "body": "pretty good!"
        },
        {
            "stars": 2,
            "body": "just ok..."
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now when positing new review data for David to a PHP script, how do I target David's specific "reviews" and append it?

I have already decoded everything correctly and have access to both the decoded file and post information. I just don't know how to target David's specific reviews in the JSON array... Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE** - Just to be clear, everything is decoded already, the POST data and the JSON file from the server. I just need to know how to target David's reviews specifically and append it.

**UPDATE 2** - Everyone, please also understand that this is in the case that the index is not known. Doing [1] would be awesome, but when someone submits, they won't know what index it is. The loop for the rendering is being done in AngularJS btw, so can't assign anything on the PHP side for the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column` or see below for an alternate:

```
$array[array_search('David', array_column($array, 'name'))]['reviews'][] = array(
    'stars'=>1,'body'=>'meh'
);
```

Instead of `array_column` you can use:

```
array_map(function($v) { return $v['name']; }, $array);
```

Comment: you so far have been the only person to understand that it is in the use case that you would not know the index, THANK YOU! I'm running 5.4 so I think I will have to install 5.5 to try this out. If you have a 5.4 solution I would mark it Accepted, gladly! :)

Comment: Just replace the `array_column` call with the `array_map` call that I posted.

Comment: This is certainly one of the coolest solutions I've come across. Worked like a charm and an effective use of array_search. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make use of a for-loop/foreach to iterate through the array testing where arr['name'] === 'David',
then you can access arr['reviews'].

```
foreach ($array as $person)
{ 
    if ($person['name'] === 'David')
    {
        $person['reviews'][] = array("stars"=> 3,"body"=> "pretty cool!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Edit:
You could also make a generic function for this

```
function findElem(arr,field,e)
{
    foreach ($arr as $elem)
    { 
        if ($elem[field] === e)
        {
            return $elem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

to call:

```
$elem = findElem(myArray,'name','David');
if ($elem !== null)
    $elem[] = array("stars"=> 3,"body"=> "pretty cool!");
```

Looks like more work, but if you are going to do it repeatedly then this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Also, wouldn't there have to be an 'array_push' somewhere?

Comment: @simplexity: `[]` appends to the `reviews` array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *specifically* david's reviews, and *only* david's reviews... assuming that $array holds the json_decoded array:

```
$david_reviews = $array[1]["reviews"];
foreach($david_reviews as $review){
    //Do code to retrieve indexes of array
    $stars = $review["stars"] //5
    $body = $review["body"] //Great!
}
```

If you're looking to grab reviews for each result, then user2225171's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Assuming that you know that David's reviews are at index 1.  Bad assumption.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I provided the secondary statement, which I can't stress enough. But OP asked for _specifically_ David's reviews, and, as of now, _only_ david's reviews.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. There is just one thing I cannot figure out: how to dynamically find the array index. Like you put [1], but what if I do not know that David is [1]. I was thinking I would look up by "name" value and then select the parent... but not sure how to do that with JSON in PHP...

Comment: @simplexity then see user2225171's answer, he has the solution you need. Loop through the array and find the sub-array with name "david". His will do exactly what you need for you.

Comment: @JamesSpence, thank you either way. It will be very helpful for other people who have that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode($json, true)` will return you the simple array of data. Then save what you need and save back with `json_encode()`

Comment: I have already decoded everything. The problem is the "save what you need" part :) What I need is to know how to append the new post review object to David's review object. How do I SPECIFICALLY target David's review and push it? Thanks!